# Find element but next of some element

Tags: jquery, filter, find, jquery-selectors

How to find some element but next of some element ?

**HTML :**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box id_1">1</div>
    <div class="box id_2">2</div>
    <div class="break">{BREAK}</div>
    <div class="box id_1">1</div>     // <--- THIS !
    <div class="box id_2">2</div>     // <--- and should work when I detect in THIS also!
</div>
```

I using `.next()` and `.filter()` seem like it doesn't work :(

```
$('#container > .box').next('.break').filter('.id_1').addClass('found');
```

**Playground :** http://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/2zBWv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `.next()` this way:

```
$('#container > .break').next('.id_1').addClass('found');
```

[**Find in fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/XkZwM/)

---

and if you want to affect `.id_1` of only first `.break` then:

```
$('#container > .break:first').next('.id_1').addClass('found');
```

[**Find this in fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/XkZwM/1/)

---

#### Update:

and if you want to affect `.id_2` then `.nextAll()` should be used:

```
$('#container > .break:first').nextAll('.id_2').addClass('found');
```

[**Find `.nextAll()` in fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/XkZwM/2/)

Comment: But, what about if i will detect `.id_2` ?

Comment: Ah....! For that you have to use `.nextAll('.id_2')`. You can replace `.next('.id_1')` to `.nextAll('.id_2')`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `.nextAll` and `.first`

```
$('#container > .box').nextAll('.break')
                      .first().next().filter('.id_1').addClass('found');
```

[**Check Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/2zBWv/1/)

Comment: Your code doesn't work , But the point this `.nextAll()` to help me + 1

Comment: Sorry , I forgot to check if i will detect `.id_2`